# Event listener and event emitter separate files

Tags: node.js, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have three files:

**my_emitter.js**: instance of EventEmitter object to be shared (let's reference this as "myEmitter")

**listener.js**: where myEmitter.on() is called

**registration_handler.js**: where myEmitter.emit() is called

---

Listener is not receiving emitted event.

With the following code, I run `node listener.js` first and then `node registration_handler.js` second.

**my_emitter.js**:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');
const myEmitter = new EventEmitter();
exports.emitter = myEmitter;
```

**listener.js**:

```
const emitterFile = require('./my_emitter');
const myEmitter = emitterFile.emitter;

myEmitter.on('test', (res) => {
    console.log('worked!');
});

//within 5s, let's run registration_handler.js to emit the event
setTimeout(console.log, 5000, 'Done');
```

**registration_handler.js**:

```
const emitterFile = require('./my_emitter');
const myEmitter = emitterFile.emitter;

myEmitter.emit('test');
```

## Console (from listener.js):

**Expected**:

```
$ node listener.js
worked!
Done
```

**Actual**:

```
$ node listener.js
Done
```

Comment: You're running 2 different node process (regardless of the file they are using), so you won't get *the* `expected`. There's messaging queue to handle what you're (I'm guessing) trying to achieve

Comment: @1556089774 i see.. is it because each node process is creating an unique instance of `EventEmitter()`? thank you!

Comment: Each `node` process have it's own *private* memory, so yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For it to work, you have to run them in the same Node.js process, for that, you can create a new file and require both your listener and emitter from there.

```js
// another-file.js

require('./listener');
require('./registration_handler.js');
```

Running this new file should give you the expected results:

```sh
$ node another-file.js
worked!
Done
```